# How to load multiple storageStates into a single context in playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation, playwright

so i want to load multiple storageStates into a single context in playwright but when i do this

```
const context = await browser.newContext({
      storageState: "telegram.json",storageState: "google.json"
    });
```

or this

```
const context = await browser.newContext({
      storageState: ["telegram.json","google.json"]
    });
```

none of the states is loaded.

But the code below will load one storageState

```
const context = await browser.newContext({
      storageState: "telegram.json"
    });
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load multiple `storageState` like that but you can do this which should achieve the same result:

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const telegramState = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('telegram.json'));
const googleState = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('google.json'));

// merge them into one
let state = { ...telegramState, ...googleState }
const context = await browser.newContext({
      storageState: state
});
```

Here we are just using the spread (...) operator to merge the two storageState objects.

Note that:

> If both objects have a property with the same name, then the second object property overwrites the first.

If that is a problem you can try `_.merge` from [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash).

Comment: states were loaded but it wasn't working, so i tried logging state,this is what was logged
https://pastebin.pl/view/66707db8

Comment: @Spidy Whoops! I forgot the `JSON.parse`- try my edited snippet